# Will an innertube for 700x35c-44c be ok for a bike that says it needs size 700x45c?

Tags: innertube, beginner

I need to replace my innertube and took a photo of the tyre mark to show the guy in the bike shop for the size. It says 700 x 45c. I bought the innertube he gave me based on this and only checked the size when I got home (yes I know, stupid me), size 700 x 35c - 44c. This range is obviously smaller (but only just) than what my tyre asks for.

Hopefully it's not a problem but wanted to check before opening the packet in case I need to return it.

What do you think? Thanks for your help in advance
Angela

Comment: It would be nice to have the next size larger, but it will work OK.

Comment: Inner tubes have a great amount of stretch built in. I've used 700x23s in a 700x35 before without issue. They won't however work the other way around. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

44c versus 45c is not enough to worry about.
You can use it.

Not that you would need to do this but after you have stretched it you should not try and put it in a 35c as it would be hard to do so without a fold in the tube.

Comment: This should work no problem, however you may have issues with patching the tube if you get a puncture since patches don't stretch a lot and may not accommodate a larger inflation size well.